# What tidyverse command can count the number of non-zero entries column-wise over a time series?

Tags: r

I have a data table that looks like the following:

```
Item        2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 
Apples        10   12   17   18    0    0
Bears         40   50   60   70   80   90
Cats           5    2    1    0    0    0
Dogs          15   17   18   15   11    0
```

I want a column that showing a count of the number of years with non-zero sales. That is:

```
Item        2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023  Count
Apples        10   12   17   18    0    0  4
Bears         40   50   60   70   80   90  6
Cats           5    2    1    0    0    0  3
Dogs          15   17   18   15   11    0  5
```

NB I'll want to do some analysis on this in the next pass, so looking to just add in the count column and not aggregate at this stage. This will be something like filter the rows if the count is greater than a threshold.

I looked at the `tally()` command from tidyverse, but this doesn't seem to do what I want (I think).

NB I haven't tagged this question as `tidyverse` due to the guidance on that tag. Shout if I need to edit this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is rowwise, we can use `rowSums` after converting the subset of dataset to logical

```
library(tidyverse)    
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Count = rowSums(.[-1] > 0))
```

---

Or using `reduce`

```
 df1 %>% 
    mutate(Count = select(., -1) %>% 
                       mutate_all(funs(. > 0)) %>% 
                       reduce(`+`))
```

---

Or with `pmap`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(Count = pmap_dbl(.[-1], ~ sum(c(...) > 0)))
#    Item 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 Count
#1 Apples   10   12   17   18    0    0     4
#2  Bears   40   50   60   70   80   90     6
#3   Cats    5    2    1    0    0    0     3
#4   Dogs   15   17   18   15   11    0     5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Item = c("Apples", "Bears", "Cats", "Dogs"), `2018` = c(10L, 
40L, 5L, 15L), `2019` = c(12L, 50L, 2L, 17L), `2020` = c(17L, 
60L, 1L, 18L), `2021` = c(18L, 70L, 0L, 15L), `2022` = c(0L, 
80L, 0L, 11L), `2023` = c(0L, 90L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Really useful. Which one would be your "go to" solution and any reason why?

Comment: @BlueOtterHat  Glad to know that it is useful for you.  The one with `rowSums` would be fast, though `reduce` can also work well.  The advantage of `rowSums` is that you can include `na.rm` argument if there are missing values